# How to blacklist an IP using apache2 without using .htaccess

Tags: apache2, ip-blocking

I have aws machine on which i'm running my spring boot application.
The public url of application is say "abc.com" i'm using apache2 to redirect request coming to abc.com to localhost:8080.

Some web servers are spamming my services and i want to block them using IP blacklisting. But i can't figure-out how.

Doesn't seem like i can use .htaccess (please tell me if i can and how)

So far i have tried to block ip through my apache2.conf with below code

```
<LocationMatch "/.*">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
SetEnvif X-Forwarded-For "148\.72\.232\.128" DenyAccess\
#repeat the SetEnvlf X-Forwarded-For ... for each IP you want to block
Deny from env=DenyAccess
</LocationMatch>
```

but its not working. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [deny network ACLs for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html), to prevent the requests from ever reaching your instance.  [Screenshots from a few years ago](http://chopmo.dk/posts/2015/06/13/blocking-traffic-in-aws.html), it will look different now.